# How to give viewing access to a certain folder through google apps scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I have a google form collecting email addresses, which is connected to a spreadsheet. Through google apps scripts (tools -> script editor) I would like to give access to the email addresses collected through the form every time a new email is added. In the spreadsheet, I have Timestamp as Column 1 and Email as Column 2, I also have other unimportant data in other columns as well. The rows do not matter. This is my code so far:

```
function giveaccess() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startColumn = 2;
  var numColumns = 99;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startColumn, 2, numColumns, 99)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddresses = row[0];
    addViewers(emailAddresses)
  }
}
```

I get the error "ReferenceError: "addViewers" is not defined." but I would like someone to tell me any other methods of doing what I mentioned above. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

I would like to bring few points into your notice :

1. addViewers() should be called on a sheet (like `sheet.addViewers(emailAddressesArray)`) and needs an array of email addresses and currently you're giving a row of sheet to it and not calling on any sheet. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addviewersemailaddresses
2. getValues() returns a two-dimensional array
3. You're fetching 99 columns, I don't why would you do that. I am not saying you're something wrong here.
4. I think you're going wrong here. Correct : `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)` Yours : `getRange(startColumn, 2, numColumns, 99)`
   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns

Suggested solution :

1. Fetch the email column
2. Put email into an array. You can use array.push(email).
3. Then call addViewers on the sheet which you want to give access and pass the email addresses array to it. Like `sheet.addViewers(emailAddressesArray);`

Efficient solution will be to add only the newly submitted email id rather than adding all the email ids.

EDIT : How to add only newly submitted email and how to give access to already existing folder.

Newly submitted responses are inserted at the bottom of the sheet so you can get the last submitted response by fetching the last row. [But I think if your form is being used **very very heavily** then this may fail. Otherwise,it's fine].

And to fetch last row, we can use `sheet.getLastRow()`

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow

You can give access to existing folder by fetching folder by id and then giving access on that.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid

Id of folder is present in the URL of that folder. (I think simple google search will guide you enough on this, so I am skipping mentioning this)

Lemme know your thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand. Is it possible for you to retype the code that I need. I hope I'm  not asking too much but I don't know Javascript (yet) EDIT: How would I have it so that it would only add the newly submitted email instead of all the emails as that would send an email to everyone that has previously signed up. And is it possible to link it an already existing google drive folder?

Comment: I have updated my answer with your points.


1. Fetch newly submitted email


2. Giving access to existing folder

Answer (score 0):

Sharing files in your Drive folder using Apps Script can be done with [setSharing(accessType, permissionType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setShareableByEditors(Boolean)):

> **setSharing(accessType, permissionType)**
>
> Sets which class of users can access the File and what permissions
>   those users are granted, besides any individual users who have been
>   explicitly given access.

sample code:

```
// Creates a folder that anyone on the Internet can read from and write to. (Domain
 // administrators can prohibit this setting for users of a G Suite domain.)
 var folder = DriveApp.createFolder('Shared Folder');
 folder.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
```

The other values for type of Access are found in [Enum Access](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access#properties):

```
- ANYONE
- ANYONE_WITH_LINK
- DOMAIN  
- DOMAIN_WITH_LINK
- PRIVATE
```

Comment: Doesn't  "var folder = DriveApp.createFolder('Shared Folder');
 folder.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);" make a bew folder everytime someone fills out the form?